# Math equation in JSON string

Tags: javascript, json, math, formatting

I'm trying to understand if I can rapresent mathematical equations in a JSON string to then retrieve it with javascript (a simple read), is there an handy, simple way to rapresent, let's say, a power, like `x^2` but with the correct format? Or maybe a polynomial `1+2x+2x^2+4x^3/3` in a correctly mathematical formatted way in the browser? I'd like to show some results in a page, retrieved from a json file (so in the json an equation would be inside a string).

Comment: I'm not sure what JSON has to do with this question but you might have a look at [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/).

Comment: I included JSON because I said that I want to format equation that are read from a json file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/) to render mathematical expressions in the browser. MathJax understands several different mathematical mark up languages that can all be stored as strings. (These strings could be wrapped in JSON objects, if desired):

- [AsciiMath](http://asciimath.org/)
- [MathML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathML)
- [TeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeX) or [LaTeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX)